# Why didn't the Avengers consider using Ant-Man this way?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-endgame

Ant-Man could have gone inside Thanos and immediately killed him by cardiac arrest.

Why didn’t the Avengers consider this plan in *Avengers: Endgame*? The plan looks incredible simple instead of all this drama.

Comment: What would that solve? The issue was to undo the *snap* not kill Thanos, he wasn't even supposed to be there.

Comment: Of course it will solve the problem, once Thanos is dead in the past anyone from the avengers could have undo the snap

Comment: No, they've already established **they can't change the past** only the present

Comment: You misunderstood when I said past it’s actually present.

Comment: I regret that I have but one downvote to give for my country.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure that the Stark Snap did kill Thanos.  It's quite possible it sent him back to 2014, possibly with a mind wipe to boot.  Honestly I'm not sure the snap/dust effect *even is killing*, it may simply be sending someone off to an aether. .

Comment: @Harper Why would Tony do that?

Comment: This plan sounds more complex than chopping off his head.

Comment: @AzorAhai well I'm not entirely sure Tony even willed that.  He may have simply desired them to go away, and nature sent them back.   However if Tony willed it, it's because he's spent the last few months dealing with MCU time travel mechanics / Avengers time-travel ethos, where things which are borrowed from the past *need to be put back*.

Comment: @Harper No, that was explicitly just the Infinity Stones that have to be put back.

Comment: @AzorAhai And Mjolnir.  But (no one seems able to answer this) if 2014 Thanos met his end in 2023, who killed half the Asgardians? Black Widow?  Seriously, where did anyone say "nothing else has to be restored"?

Comment: @Harper Well, I assume they could have kept it, they just didn't want to deprive alt!Thor of his hammer. Plus, Fat Thor has a better axe now anyway. | It's like Hulk said; you can't change things that have already happened. Wibbly wobbly and all that. Maybe the MCU is okay with paradoxes. | Hawkeye killed BW.

Comment: *Seriously, where did anyone say "nothing else has to be restored"?* Okay, maybe it would have been clearer to say "it was *only* the Infinity Stones that were described as having to be put back"

Comment: @AzorAhai well, that's the trick.  There has to be a boundary.  Obviously the baseball glove (that Hawkwye took as a test) is below the line and the Infinity stones are above it. The rest, we just don't know.

Comment: @Harper The Ancient One says that the Infinity Stones create what we perceive of as time, and that removing one would destabilize her reality, that's why they had to be returned. Mjolnir doesn't "create time," so it doesn't strictly need to be returned. I don't think there was any implication anything else had to go back.

Answer (score 5):

Ant-Man never needed to fight Thanos and in fact he was more useful to get the mini quantum tunnel in the van working again per their plan. He wasn't involved in the majority of the fight really and certainly not with any means of fighting Thanos.

Answer (score 2):

It likely wouldn't have worked. Dr. Strange had foreseen over 14 million possible outcomes of the battle and the only one that ended with an Avengers victory was the one we saw. Granted, Strange wasn't giving out any hints as to what the winning strategy was or wasn't until the very last moment but I think it's safe to say that if Ant-Man had attempted anything that wasn't part of the winning strategy, Strange would have stepped in to stop him.

Comment: These are just scripts I finally understand that they can fudge up any story they like

Comment: Obviously, the real answer to any plot-related question is "because that's how the writers wanted to write it". However, it's generally assumed that these questions are looking for in-universe explanations for why things happen a certain way, which is what my answer is. If you want to know why the writers chose this particular option instead of something else, you need to specifically mention that in your question.